# How to add Folders into Document Library using PnP Provisioning Template

Tags: 2013, document-library, folder, pnp

I'm using PnP

> GetProvisioningTemplate()

method to create Provisioning Template from existing site(have some document libraries with folders and files) and applying to newly created sites, using PnP

> ApplyProvisioningTemplate()

Its working fine interms of creation and applying themes, CSS etc.,But its not copying contents of document library.
Is there any way can include the library contents on template(XML)file.
I'm following [Link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.Framework.Console) from OfficeDev

Comment: Any Comments...

Comment: Do you have any relevant code?

Comment: @Abbas Pls check the above mentioned link. It has sample code in GitHub which is downloadable...

Answer (score 2):

To create folders within a document library, you must enter the folder within the given ListInstance. Folders can be nested to create sub-folders.

```
<pnp:ListInstance Title="My Doc Lib">
  <pnp:Folders>
    <pnp:Folder Name="1. Admin" />
    <pnp:Folder Name="2. SharePoint">
      <pnp:Folder Name="2A. PnP Sub Folder" />
    </pnp:Folder>
    <pnp:Folder Name="3. Etc" />
  </pnp:Folders>
</pnp:ListInstance>
```

Answer (score 1):

To provision folders inside custom document library, use pnp:Directory, a sub node under pnp:Files.

```
    <pnp:Files>
       <pnp:Directory Src="StyleLibrary" Folder="{sitecollection}/Style 
       Library/" Overwrite="true" Level="Published" Recursive="false" 
       IncludedExtensions="*.*" ExcludedExtensions="" MetadataMappingFile="">
      </pnp:Directory>
    </pnp:Files>
```

src="StyleLibrary", StyleLibrary is the folder to be provisioned and is placed in the same folder that the provisioning console exe is placed.